# Qt SQL Server - Hashed password

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt

I've got this line of SQL query to check the validity of a username password :

```
if exists (select * from Acc where username = :un and userpassword = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', :pw)) select 1 else select 0
```

It works correctly when executed directly in SQL Server Management studio but when I bind values and query from Qt it won't work.
What am I doing wrong? I'd appreciate any help. I'll paste the complete code section in Qt below :

```
q->prepare("if exists (select * from Acc where username = :un and userpassword = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', :pw)) select 1 else select 0");
q->bindValue(":un", un);
q->bindValue(":pw", pw);
if (q->exec())
{
    q->next();
    if (q->value(0).toInt() == 0)
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "", "User not found", QMessageBox::Ok);
    }
    else
    {
        //execute form . . . 
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `:pw` is same type in SSMS and in qt? Hash will be different for 'a' and N'a', because NCHAR have 2 bytes per character and CHAR have 1 byte.

Comment: @LeszekMazur : Thanks LeszekMazur. it is QString in Qt and nvarchar(30) in SSMS. Is that OK?

Comment: Qt for QString uses [QChar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchar.html), so both are 2 bytes characters and should work in same way, so this is probably not cause.